# Htaccess for Google Sitesearch

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm trying to bring my site's search capabilities in line with Google SiteSearch and need to extend our search URL to this: http://example.com/search?q=term with our current format as http://example.com/search.php?company=term

The htaccess I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)q=(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^search /search.php?company=%1 [L,NC,NE,QSA]
```

All I've achieved so far is a lot of 500 Errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /search\?q=([0-9a-zA-Z-_\.@]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /search.php?company=%1 [L,R]
```

I also limited the match-everything in this working version.